# What is the best software to host a ruby on rails application on production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver

Is webrick the only good option?
I know there is a way of using apache, but is it better than webrick?

Comment: Webrick is not intended for production use at all, it's for development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Four Choices

There are really four choices, well, plus *WEBrick*, but that would be an unusual choice for a production server. Approximately in order of increasing complexity...

- *nginx + Mongrel*
- *nginx + Passenger*
- *Apache + Mongrel*
- *Apache + Passenger*

(There is *Phusion Passenger Standalone*, but that's really an nginx + passenger compiled together, so I'm not counting it, although it may be a good option for some people.)

A larger site may then add specialized layer 7 hardware (NetScaler, F5, ...) in front of the servers.

Comment: Isn't passenger all that's necessary? It spawns children and proxies the request from the passenger process to them, right? What would nginx be used for?

Comment: Passenger can run on either Apache or Nginx. I think that's what he meant. It's really like a matrix -- you can have either Apache or Nginx on Passegner, or Apache or Nginx on Mongrel.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I've updated to state things more clearly.

Comment: Another option is Unicorn. Though I confess I have no experience of it.

Comment: Passenger with Apache is a good option if you need to serve other types of applications and not just Ruby/Rails. If your server already runs Apache for something else you can just add the passenger module for it. If you only intend to host Ruby/Rails/Rack apps then Nginx with Passenger is a good option.

Answer (score 3):

[Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/)... it's much better than WEBrick. Passenger is the de-facto standard for deploying on Apache. It also has options to run on an Nginx environment, or as a standalone server (like WEBrick). See this question about Passenger Standalone.

There are other less commonly used options, notably including [Mongrel](http://rubyforge.org/projects/mongrel).

Also, you might be interested in [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com), which I use. It's a cloud based production server, and has free deployment options for small sites. Heroku takes care of all the server-side for you, which is a real relief if you're not a server admin (I'm not).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is really good for Apache, but I would consider an external hosting solution. For small projects, [heroku](http://heroku.com) provides free hosting, and for large projects, you can scale as needed with relatively low prices. There are some others out there, but heroku (IMHO) gives you the most flexibility... and its FREE (and reliable)!

Answer (score 0):

Phusion Passenger is the de facto Apache mod, and yes, it's better than WEBRick (which is really only good for tiny sites or testing).

Answer (score 0):

We use heroku and  <del>despite it runs with ruby 1.8.7,</del>  I never had problems with it

Comment: You can use 1.9.2 on the Bamboo MRI (bamboo-mri-1.9.2) stack.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before: Webrick is for development only, do not use that for deploying.

The simplest replacement for Webrick is using mongrel. But that doesn't scale well (in the end). A mongrel is a single thread, so a mongrel-process can only handle one process at a time. If you have a lot of users, you will have to install many mongrel, load-balanced by an apache or nginx in front of it.

Then it depends on your server platform: on any linux flavor (ubuntu/debian/mac os) you could use apache/nginx in front of passenger, mongrel, thin, unicorn, ...

From all these options, passenger has the easiest integration.
If you use mongrel/thin/unicorn you will have to specify your own load-balancing between different instances and manage that yourself. Passenger handles that for you.

If you are on Windows passenger can't be used, but mongrel or thin are still viable (not unicorn). On Windows i would recommend using mongrel_service for each mongrel-instace you keep running, behind an apache webserver.

But heroku is the easiest of them all (if you do not have to deploy on a server inside your building).

Answer (score 0):

A good place to see the standard tools used by Rails apps is at https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/. The most popular choices are usually the best but sometimes it's good to check out alternatives for your specific use cases.